# Lawn: Newly sown turf grows at least twice as fast as the "old" turf

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

I sowed a new lawn 1-2 months ago. It grows more than twice as fast as the old lawn. I never water my lawn and it gets the same amount of sun for the whole lawn. No fertiliser either.

However, there is a big difference in the speed of growth, it looks a bit strange. The seed is not the same, I didn't know if there was a difference.

Is this normal? What could be the possible causes? How-To fix?

Comment: Could you take a picture to show us?  It would help us know if the seeds you just sowed are different from the 'old lawn'.

Comment: Some seed bags *are* fertilized. This could be it. Also, your old lawn may be in need of some care, like thatching and aerating, which might bring up the color and growth. You're new lawn was likely planted on recently mixed soil and doesn't have to compete with detritus and weeds.

Comment: You are asking if all lawn seed is the same while you say the bags were different.  No. Most all are blends. There is no mystery here unless you swear the two matched in every way. "The seed is not the same, I didn't know if there was a difference." Yes, there are big differences in grass seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some seed bags *are* fertilized. If you used such a bag, this could be causing the excess growth. If you still have a bag, or can find it in the store again, you can check and know for sure. If this is the cause, the fertilizing effects probably won't be there again in spring. Definitely not after next summer. You could begin a fertilizing regiment for your entire lawn, and it will all probably even out eventually.

Also, your old lawn may be in need of some care, like thatching and aerating, which might bring up the color and growth. Your new lawn was likely planted on recently mixed soil and doesn't have to compete with detritus and weeds. Your new lawn might not be growing faster; it could be that your old lawn is growing slower. If this is the cause, give your old lawn some TLC, and even toss a bit of fertilizer on it.

Answer (score 11):

"Fixes:"

1. wait a year and see if it's anything more than new-ness.
2. dig up and reseed the "old" lawn with the "new" seed.

One of these is a lot less work than the other...

Meanwhile, just mow the new part more often than the old.